# How to suppress patterns being treated as options in grep

Tags: linux, bash

In `grep`, when I try to find a pattern in the `man` page, the pattern is treated as the option of `grep` if it starts with `-`. For example, I find someone is using `uname -r` and I wonder what does `-r` means for uname.

```
 uname --help | grep '-r'
```

But I got the following error,

> Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
>   Try `grep --help' for more information.

Seems as if `-r` is treated as an option for `grep`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways:

1. If supported by your version, use `--` to stop argument processing.

   ```
   uname --help | grep -- '-r'
   ```
2. Use the `-e` option to specify the pattern. Since it expects an argument,
    `grep` will not treat the next string as a new option just because it starts with a hyphen.

   ```
   uname --help | grep -e '-r'
   ```

Answer (score 4):

As described in the man page for grep:

> -e PATTERN, --regexp=PATTERN
>
> Use  PATTERN as the pattern.  This can be used to specify multiple search patterns, or to protect a pattern beginning with a hyphen (-).  (-e is specified by POSIX.)

`uname --help | grep -e -r` does what is expected.

Answer (score 1):

Backslash also seems to help:

```
uname --help | grep "\-r"
uname --help | grep '\-r'
```

Comment: interesting, escape the -